# how to get ajax request content

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, fullcalendar

In my symfony project, i try to get a ajax request content in a dump() to check datas. The objective is to processes this datas to do a sql request. In my controler when i do a dump, unfortunately I have not return??

this my js:

```
eventResize: function(event) {
        console.log("eventResize : ok");
        var start1 = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end1 = event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/.../update',
            data: 'action=update&title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start1 + '&end=' + end1 + '&id=' + event.id,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            },
        });
    },
```

and this my controler:

```
public function updateEventAction(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
  {
      dump($request->request->get(''));die();
  }

}
```

Can anybody help me, please!!!???

Comment: better to pass your data as an object e.g. `data: { "action": "update", "title": event.title, "start": start1` ...etc. Then you won't run into any URL-encoding issues from making a raw querystring naively like you're doing. Instead jQuery will take care of it for you. Anyway, if you get no response, check your browser's console and network tab for errors and see what's there. That'll start giving you a clue what went wrong. You can see the actual ajax request itself and see what status and response content (if any) was returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are making AJAX request to dev environment.

That die will stop symfony execution, so dump will never be printed.

You can debug it from profiler.

On the left menu of the profiler page you can get to see old requests by using the "Last 10" button. Choose the request you'd like to see and there you should be able to see your dump at "debug" section.

also, take in mind that your code will fail because symfony controller must return a Response type (`return new Response()`)